# Why do we need to write function's generic in typescript? For example function fill<IDontKnow>(){}

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript so I have questions about it. One of them is this:

```
function fill**<IDontKnow>**(array: any[], value: IDontKnow): IDontKnow[] {
  return array.map(() => value);
}
```

I understand the purpose of all the written generics but the one in asterisks. What does it mean/do?

Comment: By providing a type for `IDontKnow` as a generic, you're telling the compiler that the `value` argument will be that type and the output will be an array of that type

Comment: How do you think this should be written, without declaring a type parameter for the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) is generally used for two purposes:

1. To tell the compiler to infer/substitute a type from a reference.
2. To tell the compiler to force a type onto a target.

Check this example based on your snippet ([or view in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbVAeAKgPgBQCGATkQQJ4BciBYZA2gLoA0iAbgaiAKZVYCUvRogDeAKESIiXKCCJJipMgDoAtgQAOePH0QBeHGw7c+AblEBfUVYD0AKkQAFWergBnLogCMvOIihd0PwALDwg4FXU0LiI-XxgwYGjrVxAAI1dYGX9qPzJ1D2AicJypRKlILiVEW2sba0QsRBhXahAocIJYCA5UMiaE6KkAE2oWgAMMoniAczHc-JYaEfi-WSQoEPmPOGBEMfiygAY55tb2tS6evoPBrhGCccmZxjGlUTCwDP6jvWQ0VDwdDAIHQLGBoMQ4NQzEQAHIQug4LDTHUGk0WgQ2h1LuhrgMSHdRntgSpUtE5lA8lxFmBlus1sEPJT8ogdnsbkRPCcMViLjBurjvrd7uMSWSiC83h8vhzPL8UOhAVCwSDUCr0DDPCjRNZ6o1Tpjzp1+VchQSRXtUnA4KguDQKVSaXTVnJGVtWbt9viAEzcs7Yk2CjnDIljK02u1gSXvBAyn3y-5K1XqtWQ1Uw4AcdzanX2JxEFzuRDenx+AKoN1hCJRGLtZBwIgQDwEd0IOstqDEabSKo1VH6lrABtNkZ1sl7J5gWYsVy+MBwADubrG7E4XDmXZAKi4YCgiCCBFYTN845bq+4HvdEygUynrxjnz3Q8bXEOCfQGEn03wQOTaYhUKaqYEiILqiCuEEcAgiMgwNv26L1i+o4nh4YxiuSM5zouy7nuu1BENMW47nuB5HrEiCnoYa6XsyqHoUQ97Sk+w5cHKuh-B+9E-sq-6poBLCZqg2YmCBYEQVBqAwSQcE6nqCHPiO5HjmG1q2vamGQthGyobhG4EURu77oex4Uc2VEXmytGWqpkaMbGzEvt676YOGalgNxf48fxcIIqgSLARIYmQdBiCwUQQA)):

```
function fill<T>(array: any[], value: T): T[] {
  return array.map(() => value);
}


/* Purpose 1: To tell the compiler to infer/substitute a type from a reference. */

// T is automatically inferred as `string` type, and in turn the type of `infer0` is automatically inferred as `string[]`.
const infer0 = fill([null, null, null], 'hello');

// T is automatically inferred as `number` type, and in turn the type of `infer1` is automatically inferred as `number[]`.
const infer1 = fill([null, null, null], 1);

// T is automatically inferred as `boolean` type, and in turn the type of `infer2` is automatically inferred as `boolean[]`.
const infer2 = fill([null, null, null], false);


/* Purpose 2: To tell the compiler to force a type onto a target. */

// T is forced to be `string`, so now the `value` argument have to be a value of type `string`.
const force0 = fill<string>([null, null, null], 1);   // should error

// T is forced to be `number`, so now the `value` argument have to be a value of type `number`.
const force1 = fill<number>([null, null, null], false);   // should error

// T is forced to be `boolean`, so now the `value` argument have to be a value of type `boolean`.
const force2 = fill<boolean>([null, null, null], 'hello');   // should error
```

The `fill**<T>**` is just a syntax to declare a generic with name `T`, where `T` can be any name.

It's the same concept as variable declaration. When you do `const T = 'hello'`, you are declaring a constant variable and naming it `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Is you new on typescript or is you new on software development? Generics is not a Typescript thing, a lot of languages out there use them: java, c#; just to name a few.

Basically the only purpose of ‘em is to have a dry type of thing going on.

```
const VALUE = Symbol(“value”);
const NEXT = Symbol(“next”);

class Node<T> {
  private [VALUE]: T;
  private [NEXT]: T;

  constructor(value: T) {
    this[VALUE] = value;
    this[NEXT] = null;
  }
}
```

As you can see up there we made a generic class the shape of them nodes can be limited by your imagination or the imagination of each of us. I is using this example bcuz it is in a every single day of a Poor Java divelopa.

Now let’s do the list class

```
const ROOT =Symbol(“root”);
const SIZE = Symbol(“size”);

type Item<T> = Node<T>;

class LinkedList<ITem {
[ROOT]: Item<
  constructor() {
    this.root = null; // first/head/root element
    this.size = 0; // total number of elements in the list
  }

  // ...
}
```